# FIle transfering in Android using ASmack as client and OpenFire as server

Tags: android, openfire, smack, asmack

I was facing problems while sending images using asmack using its built in methods.
I convert pictures and then convert them into Base64 string and then send it and at the receiver end just reconvert it into bitmap and get the original image in a few seconds

Comment: I have used the above method for sending images which are not greater than 1 mb

Comment: I will sooner post the overall code also

Comment: see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371701/how-to-send-media-content-in-chat-application